# Is $(X,\rho)$ a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have the following problem:

---

Let $X$ denote the collection of all differentiable continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'$ is continuous. For $f, g \in X$, let
$$\rho(f, g) = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \left | f'(x) - g'(x) \right |.$$

Show that $\rho$ is a metric on $X$ and that $(X, \rho)$ is complete.

---

So, when showing that  $\rho$ is a metric on $X$ we see that $\rho(f,g) \ge 0$ since it's an absolute value.

But is it true that $\rho(f,g) = 0$ iif $f = g$ ? Those derivatives and the condition that $f(0) = 0$ are confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

If $\rho(f,g)=0$ then $f'-g'=0$ on $[0,1]$. This implies that $f-g$ is constant. Since $f(0)=g(0)=0$ this implies $f-g=0$ or $f=g$.